# Loop skipping in php

Tags: php

How do I skip a loop and go to the next one? Lets say my query in a loop returns result 'Nothing', I want to skip updating the base and go to the next loop. If I have 7 loops and my 5th loop returns 'Nothing' from my base, skip it don't do nothing beyond that point and just go to the next, 6th loop.

I have a for loop like so:

```
for((int) $i = 0; $i < $number_of_updates; $i++) 
{
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    list($name) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        if ($name = 'Nothing')
        {
            go to next loop;
        }

    updating my database and stuff; 
}
```

EDIT: I have a $_SESSION variable at the end that stores all of my loops and displays them. I also don't want results with 'Nothing' to be stored there.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. Entering `Loop skipping in php` into Google gives you the correct answer

Comment: I should also add that continue; function quits my entire loop

Comment: That would be very odd. How do you test this? (Edit: ah, Marty solved the mystery)

Comment: Compare using two `=`, you are **assigning** a value there, not comparing. `if ($name == 'Nothing') { continue; }`

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! I was comparing yea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) will end the current iteration and start the next one:

```
if ($name == 'Nothing')
// -------^^ Make sure you're using double (==).
{
    continue;
}
```

Comment: oddly continue; quits my loop entirely

Comment: @Van Note the double `==` - your question has one which means you're running continue every iteration.

Comment: my god, you are right! Thank you! Can I also ask you how to group same results in one. Lets say my foreach ($_SESSION['item'] as $output) returns multiple results for that loop but if there are same results I want them only outputed once

Comment: @Van No, that should be a separate question (which I'll be happy to help out with if I stumble upon it).

Comment: they blocked my question asking abilities again, happens everytime I receive downvotes... Ah well thanks for the help, I appreciate it!